# What are some nice algorithms/techniques for optimizing and predicting Click Through Rates (CTR)?

Tags: r, python, optimization

Definition of Click Through Rates:

> CTR is the number of clicks that your ad receives divided by the
>   number of times your ad is shown expressed as a percentage (clicks ÷
>   impressions = CTR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a group of algorithms (or techniques) called the [Bandit algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit), which deal especially with the problem statement, which is the optimization of Click-through rates of advertisements.

The problem is framed in a setting of multiple bandits with vending machines. There are various strategies which can be implemented:

- Epsilon-greedy strategy
- Epsilon-first strategy
- Epsilon-decreasing strategy
- Contextual Epsilon strategy

[Reference on why Bandit algorithms are better than A/B testing frameworks.](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2012/bandit_algorithms_vs_ab.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) is very common and efficient.

This will provide you with a probability of click for a given impression. You will likely need additional information for optimization, like keywords or A/B testing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah, it is one of the methods. And I have found Bandit algorithms perform really nice (better than Logistic and A/B).  Please have a look at my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the following algorithms:

1. **[Factorization Machines](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b97053/paper/Rendle2010FM.pdf) by Steffen Rendle** - 
   Really good algorithm for sparse feature sets, in construct to polynomial-regression.
   Measures the interaction between features. Model that in addition to learning linear weights on features, learn a vector space for each feature to learn pairing interactions between features in this new space.
2. **Field-Aware Factorization Machines** - an improvement of the FM model.
   Recently, have been used to win two Kaggle's click-through rate prediction competitions.
3. **FTRL - "Follow The (Proximally) Regularized Leader" algorithm** - regularized online logistic regression. Equivalent to Online (Stochastic) Gradient Descent when no regularization is used. Very easy to implement.
4. **[AdPredictor](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=122779) algorithm by Microsoft** 
   The algorithm is based on a probit regression model that maps discrete or real-valued input features to probabilities. It maintains Gaussian beliefs over weights of the model and performs Gaussian online updates derived from approximate message passing.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain a bit more about them?

Comment: Added information in my comment. Please note that in my opinion any of these algorithm can't really be explained in one line, you'll have to read the articles.

Comment: In addition, do you have code implementation of a Bandit algorithm? I would give it try on my dataset.

Comment: Is there an open-source implementation or at least a binary for Microsoft's AdPredictor?

Comment: @Ahmedov see: [link] (https://github.com/ajtulloch/adpredictor) in Python and this: [link] (https://github.com/mayconbordin/adpredictor-java) in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can see nice algorithms in kaggle competitions about CTR:

- https://www.kaggle.com/c/avito-context-ad-clicks
- https://www.kaggle.com/c/avazu-ctr-prediction

Just go to forum of each competition and search for winning solutions ;)

Comment: and one more 
 - https://www.kaggle.com/c/criteo-display-ad-challenge

Answer (score 1):

Factorization machines - [libfm](http://www.libfm.org/) open source software has been used widely among top companies in recommender applications.

Check it out. It contains various algorithms to play with (e.g. stochastic gradient descent).

I guess your data has like "click/view" label for each pair of user-product or say cookie-advertisement saying *"whether user clicked or just viewed product"*. You can treat this as binary classification with two classes click or just view.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on your answer

Comment: edited. Check it out. Hope its useful.

Comment: I really didn't apply this till now.  (Would do it though).  As I have self-answered, using the Bandit algorithms proved very useful.